# UICollectionView's Header's height dependent on its content in Swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, uicollectionview, height, uicollectionreusableview

Inside a `UICollectionView` I have a `HeaderView` within a `UILabel`. `numberOfLines` is set to zero to change label's `height` based on its text. I want the header's `height` to depend on the label's `frame`.

PS.
`HeaderView` in UICollectionView is not as simple as a `common view` or even `UITableViewCell`. This feature works with them pretty easy unlike with `UICollectionReusableView`.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2

Answer (score 0):

Find the height of your label using this function:-

```
func labelHeight(width:CGFloat , font:UIFont , text:String)->CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

add this UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method into your controller and find the height and return header size here

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
  let height = labelHeight(width: collectionView.bounds.width, font:pass the labelFont here , text:"Pass label text here")

return CGSize(width:collectionView.bounds.width , height: height + 10)
}
```